# Python -- var getting set without me setting it, I may be losing my mind

Tags: python, libvlc

This should be so simple, but I just can't see what's going on here:

```
def playlist_item_added(self, _):
        temp_playlist = self.playlist_olv.GetObjects()
        if not self.mirror_playlist:
            self.mirror_playlist = temp_playlist
            for item in self.mirror_playlist:
                self.vlc_playlist.add_media(u.http_space_escape(item["loc"]))
            self.vlc_player.set_media_list(self.vlc_playlist)
            print "if"
            print self.mirror_playlist
        else:
            print "else"
            print self.mirror_playlist
            for index, item in enumerate(temp_playlist):
                if not item == self.mirror_playlist[index]:
                    media = vlc.Media(u.http_space_escape(item["loc"]))
                    #self.mirror_playlist.insert(index, item)
                    self.vlc_playlist.lock()
                    self.vlc_playlist.insert_media(media, index)
                    self.vlc_playlist.unlock()
```

The problem is `self.mirror_playlist` seems to be getting added to without me asking.  I just can't see why.  This is an event handler, when something gets added to my list, it comes here.  It checks if `self.mirror_playlist` has been set already -- if not, it sets it, no problem.  If it is set already, it adds to it (the else block).

Notice the prints I put in.  When I add the first item, everything goes as planned.  When I add the second item, the `print self.mirror_playlist` just after the else prints that the second item has already been added to it.  Further, I even commented out the part of the code that inserts into that list as you can see in the middle of the `else` block.

I checked every last line of code and the `mirror_playlist` attribute isn't mentioned anywhere else except in this function and in the constructor where it sets to `None`.  I double-checked the indents, I double-checked with prints that the flow is exactly how it should be (it is).  How is this variable getting added to?  I'm almost certain it's something so simple that I can't see it.

Comment: You've only shown a member function of some unknown class.  There isn't enough to really reproduce the problem.  Also, what is `GetObjects()` returning?  Does it create a new list each time?  If not, then that could be your problem.

Comment: Do `self.mirror_playlist = temp_playlist[:]` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro, that did it.  I used the equivalent "=list(temp_playlist)" so it's more readable.

Tom Karzes -- my apologies.  GetObjects returns a list, it's from ObjectListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the first item, you are not copying the list, change that line to:

```
self.mirror_playlist = temp_playlist[:]
```

Comment: That did it -- I forgot about copying lists.  For future readers, lists are just pointers to memory, to copy a list, you can't simply assign a different variable to it as you can with most other items.  For reference, I used "=list(temp_playlist)" which does the same thing as the answer but a bit more readable.